# How to use dart-sdk (dart2native) along with flutter/dart-sdk on Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

I initially had the Flutter SDK installed as I have been working on a desktop application and started a mini side project for a CLI tool I wanted to make in Dart. I just finished it last night and wanted to build it and considering Flutter had the `flutter build` command, I expected it would be the same for Dart, but this was my first time trying to make something in pure Dart, so didn't realize it was a bit different. After wondering for a few moments why running "Build project" in IntelliJ output "build successful", yet yielded no executable, I tried to run `dart build` and `pub build` and saw that those didn't exist, which of course eventually lead me to dart2native, which it turns out the Flutter SDK doesn't have.

I pulled down the most current SDK (as of last night) and went to try and use dart2native, but so far no matter what I try, such as `dart2native bin\myfile.dart` or `dart2native bin/myfile.dart -o bin\myfile.exe`, etc, I always just end up getting "The system cannot find the path specified."

My env path was originally set to the Flutter included dart-sdk as it was supposed to be for using/building flutter, so i tried to change it to the newly pulled dart-sdk and restarted, but still ended up with the same error.

Does anyone have any recommendations? Is there something I am missing/not doing properly? I don't exactly know where to go from here and Google results for "windows dart2native" are quite limited.

Thanks,
-MH

Answer (score 0):

It looks like installing the dart-sdk via choco ended up being ok and doesn't seem to be interfering with Flutter as I thought it might. So it seems like doing it that way took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, dart2native is not a binary, its a bat script. So assuming you have setup the path of your dart bin folder in your PATH.

You can do,

`dart2native.bat main.dart`

And it will generate a main.exe file which is AOT compiled binary of your dart code. Optionally you can pass -o flag to change the name of the output binary.

`dart2native.bat main.dart -o mydartbinary.exe` will output a mydartbinary.exe file.

Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it figured out. The main issue seemed to have been with how I had things set up if I remember correctly. I installed the Dart SDK via choco and everything worked as expected.